# How to add yii to environment variables?

Tags: php, yii

I am going to install yii on windows 7. what sholud I add to environment variables. I mean what should I add to path in my computer> properties > advance> environment variable

Answer (score 0):

have a read of this - this should get you running:
https://github.com/marcovtwout/yii-environment/blob/master/README.md

Recommends an install through composer to sort your dependancies out ;-)

Thanks,
//P